# Command works normally in Shell, but not while using a script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I used this command in my Bash Shell:

```
printf $VAR1 >> `printf $VAR2`
```

and it normally worked. But when I write this into the script file and run it in Shell, it does not work. File "script.sh" contains this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf $VAR1 >> `printf $VAR2`
```

and the output in Shell is:

```
script.sh: line2: `printf $VAR2`: ambiguous redirect
```

I don´t know, how is this possible, because the command is absolutely the same. And of course, I run the script on the same system and in the same Shell window.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: your script needs to define `VAR1` and `VAR2`, i.e. `VAR1=$1; VAR2=$2` (Just assuming about $1 and $2). Good luck.

Comment: Unless `VAR1` and `VAR2` are (exported) environment variables, they aren't visible in the script so you are redirecting to an empty string, which is 'ambiguous' (or nonsensical, if you prefer).

Comment: In the first case scenario, what does this command return: `echo $SHELL; echo $VAR1; echo $VAR2`

Comment: BTW using printf with just a single argument is kind of pointless, you may as well use echo.

Comment: @BjornMunch: Using a _command substitution_ in this case is pointless (and fragile), because a simple variable reference - `>> "$VAR2"` - will do; `printf` with a single argument does have its uses, namely to _portably_ print a literal containing control-character escapes (e.g., `\n`), or, in their absence, to print a literal without a trailing newline.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: You're absolutely right, but, in terms of the error message's wording,  'ambiguous' vs. 'nonsensical' is more than a matter of preference:
'ambiguous' is misleading in this case, because attempting to write to a file without a name is unambiguously nonsensical; by contrast, trying to redirect to an empty-string _literal_ at least yields a (slightly) more meaningful `No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 points worth addressing here:

**Shell variables vs. environment variables:**

- Scripts (unless invoked with `.` / `source`) run in a *child* process that only sees the parent [shell]'s *environment* variables, not its regular *shell* variables.

  - This is what likely happened in the OP's case: `$VAR1` and `$VAR2` existed as regular *shell* variables, but not *environment* variables, so script `script.sh` didn't see them.
- Therefore, for a child process to see a parent shell's shell variables, the parent must *export* them first, as a result of which they (also) become environment variables: `export VAR1=... VAR2=...`

**Bash's error messages relating to output redirection (`>`, `>>`)**:

- If the filename argument to a an output redirection is an - *unquoted* [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (`` `...` ``, or its modern equivalent, `$(...)`) - i.e., the output from a *command* - Bash reports error `ambiguous redirect` in the following cases:

  - The command output has embedded whitespace, i.e., contains *more than one word*.
  - The command output is *empty*, which is what likely happened in the OP's case.

    - As an aside: In this case, the error message's wording is unfortunate, because there's nothing ambiguous about a missing filename - it simply cannot work, because files need names.
- It is generally advisable to *double-quote* command substitutions (e.g., `>> "$(...)"`) and also variable references (e.g., `"$VAR2"`): this will allow you to return filenames with embedded whitespace, and, should the output be unexpectedly empty, you'll get the (slightly) more meaningful error message `No such file or directory`.

  - *Not* double-quoting a variable reference or command substitution subjects its value / to so-called [*shell expansions*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html): further, often unintended interpretation by the shell.

**The wisdom of using a command substitution to generate a filename**:

Leaving aside that `printf $VAR2` is a fragile way to print the value of variable `$VAR2` in general (the robust form again involves double-quoting: `printf "$VAR2"`, or, even more robustly, to rule out inadvertent interpretation of escape sequences in the variable value, `printf %s "$VAR2"`), there is *no good reason to employ a command substitution to begin with* if all that's needed is a variable's value:

`>> "$VAR2"` is enough to robustly specify the value of variable `$VAR2` as the target filename.

Answer (score -2):

I tried this on my Mac (10.11.1) in a terminal window and it worked fine.

Are you sure your default shell is bash?

```
echo $SHELL
```

Did you use EXPORT to set your shell vars?

```
$ export VAR1="UselessData"
$ export VAR2="FileHoldingUselessData"
$ ./script.sh
$ cat FileHoldingUselessData
UselessData$
```

However.... echo I think does a better job since with printf the output terminates with the first space so....

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo $VAR1 >> `printf $VAR2`

$ ./script.sh
$ cat FileHoldingUselessData
Some Useless Data
```

Which leads me to believe you might want to just use echo instead of printf all together..

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $VAR1 >> `echo $VAR2`
```

Comment: Using a _command substitution_ in this case is pointless (and fragile), because a simple variable reference - `>> "$VAR2"` - will do. (As an aside: `echo` doesn't help, unless you double-quote the entire command substitution.)

Comment: Whether `bash` is the default shell doesn't enter the picture: the script references bash explicitly (via shebang line `#!/bin/bash`), and environment variables are shell-independent.

Comment: Using `printf` is often a better choice than `echo`.  Using it was not a factor in the problem here.

Comment: Auhauch probably just needs to use export as I mentioned above.  Regarding echo, my point was that without knowing the value of $VAR2 there is no way of knowing if printf was going to give the desired result since the way he coded it, printf wouldn't have behaved as nicely with spaces.

Comment: The immediate problem with `printf` can be fixed by double-quoting the variable reference, which is generally the right thing to do: `printf "$VAR2"` or, more robustly, `printf %s "$VAR2"`.
However, my point was that your `echo` solution will also break with filenames with embedded spaces, because the command substitution as a whole isn't double-quoted: try `echo foo > $(echo a b)`.

Comment: _With_ double-quoting, you can make both `printf` and `echo` work (`echo "$VAR1" >> "$(echo "$VAR2")"` or `echo "$VAR1" >> "$(printf %s "$VAR2")"`), but the real issue is that there is no good reason to employ a command substitution to begin with, so your advice is not only broken, but attempts to fix something that's not worth fixing. `echo "$VAR1" >> "$VAR2"` is the proper solution. (The only conceivable reason to involve `printf` is if the variable contained escape sequences that `printf` should interpret, but I doubt that's the case here.)

Comment: You've clearly put effort into your answer, and I don't mean to discourage you, but as it currently stands I believe your answer does more harm than good.